# Finishing The Splash Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, splash-screen

The splash screen will not finish when you go to the home screen by the screen button then click on the app again to open it, It just returns to the splash screen? why is that

i'm calling finish(); so why wouldn't it be working confused

```
package com.webcraftbd.radio;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

public class SplashScreen extends Activity
{
    // Set the display time, in milliseconds (or extract it out as a configurable parameter)
    private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 3000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        // Obtain the sharedPreference, default to true if not available
        boolean isSplashEnabled = sp.getBoolean("isSplashEnabled", true);

        if (isSplashEnabled)
        {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    //Finish the splash activity so it can't be returned to.
                    SplashScreen.this.finish();
                    // Create an Intent that will start the main activity.
                    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                    SplashScreen.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                }
            }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
        }
        else
        {
            // if the splash is not enabled, then finish the activity immediately and go to main.
            finish();
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
            SplashScreen.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
        }
    }}
```

Comment: try this :             
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
SplashScreen.this.startActivity(mainIntent);SplashScreen.this.finish(); You should startActivity first and then finish your splashscreen.

Comment: Why are you using a splash screen in the first place? This is an Android anti-pattern and goes against the design guidelines.

Comment: I try that an let you know if it works.
Because it make the app look more professional in my opinion lots of apps use splash screens probably to lead other things load

Comment: Plenty of splash screens here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21989199/android-cancelable-splash-screen/21989492#21989492

Comment: Thanks ;)
Not sure why the current one wasnt working followed that off you tube so it should worked and I done that tuorial before with luck

Comment: um.........................

Answer (score 0):

if its just a splash screen why u dont use something simple ? Like;

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle radioPlayer) {
        super.onCreate(radioPlayer);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Thread splash= new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    sleep(3000);
                    startActivity(new Intent("com.test.MAINMENU"));
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally {
                    finish();
                }
            }

        };
        splash.start();
    }
```

Comment: tried that didn't work :/
in the main fest xml I do have it set to the splash screen as the main launcher could be why but noone else has problems weird

and thanks ;)